# SQL query: join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

so i get an error on the this sql query, but i can´t see my mistake myself:

```
SELECT group_members.group_id, 
       group_members.permissions, 
       group.group_name
  FROM group_members, 
       group 
 WHERE group_members.group_id=group.group_id
   AND group.group_id = 1
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group WHERE group_members.group_id=group.group_id AND group.group_id = 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it is considering `Group` as a Keyword. try using `JOIN` to join the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group is a reserved word in MySQL either enclose it in backticks "`" or better yet do not use it as a table name

```
SELECT group_members.group_id, group_members.permissions, `group`.group_name
FROM group_members, `group` 
WHERE group_members.group_id=`group`.group_id
AND `group`.group_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Gordon, had a brain fart and couldn't remember how to format the query block, was just looking it up when it said it had been edited

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT group_members.group_id, group_members.permissions, `group`.group_name
FROM group_members, group 
WHERE group_members.group_id=`group`.group_id
AND `group`.group_id = 1
```